# two "and" to summarise sentences

Tags: conjunctions

I want to say,

> - My skills in data management
> - My experiences in data management
> - My skills in programming
> - My experiences in programming

in one sentence:

> my skills and experiences in data and programming

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Does this convey what I want to say?

My concern is this sentence

> My skills and experiences in data and programming"

sounds like

> "My skills and experiences in data" + "programming"

treating programming as an independent item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "both". It makes it unambiguous.

> My skills and experiences in both data and programming ...

You're correct that alone it's not completely clear and it is possible that someone could misunderstand what you mean... it's unlikely, though, it may depend on what you say after programming. Right now you're not giving us the full sentence.

Either way, if you want to be absolutely clear, say "both" and you'll be set.

Comment: ah...that's clever!

Answer (score 1):

When job hunting, "skills" and "experiences" are somewhat synonymous, yet at the same time meaningless.  Everyone has "skills" and "experiences" so why belabor the point?  Just pick one or the other, and concentrate instead on *what kind* of skills/experience you have that would make you a valuable employee.

> **My experience in data management and programming** makes me the ideal candidate for this position.  I worked for ten years managing, *etc.*

In a different context using two *ands* is fine, assuming you want both items in the first part to apply to both items in the second part:

> The story tells of **the lives and loves** of **Bartelby and James**, winemakers of reknown.

If you want to separate out the items of the first part to only apply to one item of the separate, it's best to use a comma or even a period to break them up.

> I have advanced skills and extensive experience in data management, as well as some programming ability.

This is awkward, though.  I'm not sure why you want to separate out programming, except to point out you're not as skilled -- in which case, why mention it at all?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, skills and experiences are synonyms 
:)